# In Jenkins, how can I set the "Branches to build" configuration option of the Pipeline plugin identical to the value of ${BRANCH_NAME}

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As you can see in the attached screenshot, I want my pipeline to fetch the Jenkinsfile from the same branch that is passed in as a parameter and saved in the `BRANCH_NAME` variable:

[image: Jenkins Pipeline]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to uncheck "Lightweight checkout" to make Jenkins parse the ${BRANCH_NAME} parameter under the Pipeline SCM settings:

[image: Pipeline SCM settings - Lightweight checkout]

Answer (score 1):

See below:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "${BRANCH_NAME}"]],  [[credentialsId: 'CRED_ID', url: 'https://url.goes.here']]])
```

To be more explicit, you could use `${params.BRANCH_NAME}`

Comment: If I do that (see [here](https://imgur.com/j3iEphz)), I get this error: `stderr: fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/${params.BRANCH_NAME}`.

Comment: Oops. I left it in single quotes. Make sure you double quote it. Answer edited.